# Excel VBA code to copy several ranges to specific sheet in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I found some code here that copies my data to another sheet which works fine. I am trying to extend it so that it copies to another Workbook and  Specific Worksheet.

```
Sub Put_Data()
Dim lastrowDB As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim arr1, arr2, i As Integer

With Sheets("GasMe18-19")
    lastrowDB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1
End With

arr1 = Array("A", "G", "H", "L")
arr2 = Array("Q", "R", "S", "T")

For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    With Sheets("GasMe18-19")
         lastrow = Application.Max(4, .Cells(.Rows.Count,   arr1(i)).End(xlUp).row)
         .Range(.Cells(4, arr1(i)), .Cells(lastrow, arr1(i))).Copy
         Sheets("Sheet1").Range(arr2(i) & 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

How can this be modified to put the data ranges into another Workbook? I put Sheet1 in the home Workbook and everything seems fine and I like the existing code base. The originating Workbook.Worksheet has 4 columns of data that I add to every few days. I then copy and paste into another Workbook2.WorkSheet2 for plotting. I prefer to copy everything from Row 4 to the last row of data for the 4 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to qualify your range with the workbook in question

```
Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbTarget As Workbook
Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
Set wbTarget = Workbooks("TheTargetWBName")

...

For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    With wbSource.Worksheets("GasMe18-19")
         lastrow = Application.Max(4, .Cells(.Rows.Count, arr1(i)).End(xlUp).Row)
         .Range(.Cells(4, arr1(i)), .Cells(lastrow, arr1(i))).Copy
         wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(arr2(i) & 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
Next
```

Take note how the `sheets("Sheet1").Range(arr2(i) & 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` line has now been fully qualified with the target workbook, using the previously declared variable `wsTarget`. This variable was first set to the name of the workbook using the line:

```
Set wbTarget = Workbooks("TheTargetWBName")
```

If the target workbook is not open, then you would simply change to

```
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("TheTargetWBName")
```

Comment: Works great but how would I check if the target Workbook was open in my instance of Excel and use the appropriate wbTarget ?